# Open sets in $\mathbb{R}$ and $\mathbb{R^2}$

Tags: general-topology, complex-analysis

I have two questions of open sets in $\mathbb{R}$ and $\mathbb{R^2}$, which come from Rudin's Real and Complex Analysis:

1. He wrote: "If $X$ is a metric space and if $\tau$ is the collection of all sets $E\subset X$ which are arbitrary open balls, then $\tau$ is a topology". Then he concluded: "in the real line $\mathbb{R}$ a set is open iff it is a union of segments $(a,b)$". I don't understand why he can conclude that, because $\tau$ is not the only topology in $\mathbb{R}$.
2. I need an explanation for the statement "Every open set $V$ in the plane is a countable union of rectangles with sides parallel to the axes". Why the rectangles, not the open discs, and why countable?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't understand the first statement you cite. If $\tau$ is the collection of open balls, then it is in general not a topology, since the intersection of open balls is usually not a ball. An exception is the metric space $\Bbb R$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the first problem, there is only one topology on $\mathbb{R}$, and hence on $\mathbb{R}^n$, which is useful to the study of analysis and that is the Euclidean topology.  Yes there are other topologies you can induce on the real number line, but that doesn't mean that they're all metrizable.  The most interesting constructions of continuity, and especially differentiability occur when considering the Euclidean topology.

For the second, if $U \subseteq \mathbb{R}^2$ is open consider the union of all boxes of the form $(a_1, b_1) \times (a_2,b_2) \subseteq U$ where $a_1,b_1, a_2, b_2 \in \mathbb{Q}$.  This forms a countable union of boxes and if $p \in U$  then there is a ball of radius $\epsilon>0$ such that $B_\epsilon(p) \subseteq U$.  If $p = (p_1,p_2)$ then consider the box $\left (p_1 - \frac{\epsilon}{\sqrt{2}}, p_1+\frac{\epsilon}{\sqrt{2}} \right ) \times \left (p_2 - \frac{\epsilon}{\sqrt{2}}, p_2 + \frac{\epsilon}{\sqrt{2}} \right )$.  Now if $q$ is inside this box then

$$
d(p,q) \;\; <\;\; \sqrt{\frac{\epsilon^2}{2} + \frac{\epsilon^2}{2}} \;\; =\;\; \epsilon
$$

where the inequality is due to the fact that if $q = (q_1,q_2)$ then $|p_i - q_i| < \frac{\epsilon}{\sqrt{2}}$ for each $i$.  We therefore have that $q \in B_\epsilon(p)$ hence the box is fully contained in $U$.  This proves that $U$ is equal to the countable union of boxes with rational coordinates properly contained in $U$.